# null pointer when setText of a EditText

Tags: android

Thsi is my code:

```
EditText editCategoryName, editBrandName;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter1, myAdapter2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
//      mylist2 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        myList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        editCategoryName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCategoryName);
        editBrandName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editBrandName);
        editCategoryName.setText("Google is your friend.", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editCategoryName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="請輸入分類名稱"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSpinnerBrand"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerBrand"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editBrandName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>
```

The null pointer error shows that in line:

```
editCategoryName.setText("Google is your friend.", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

I don't know why. Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After  `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
this line you forget `setContentView(R.layout.<xml file name>)`

Answer (score 5):

you haven't define `setContetnView(R.layout.xyz);`
in oncreate method.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to define setContentView(R.layout.you_xml_name); in onCreate method.

```
EditText editCategoryName, editBrandName;
private ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter1, myAdapter2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.you_xml_name);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    myList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    editCategoryName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCategoryName);
    editBrandName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editBrandName);
    editCategoryName.setText("Google is your friend.", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the     setContentView("id of your layout file");      before you use the id's of the edit text and spinners inside the xml file. Else it will show null pointer as you are trying to use an id which is a part of an XML layout which you haven't used.